# NameError Name is not defined how do i fix it?

Tags: python

```
print("Hi! This program has a lot of errors, please fix them ")
print("What class is this?")

the_class = input()
if the_class == UST220:
     print("Correct, this is", the_class)
else:
     print("Oh, you seem to not be in the right class.")

print("I would like to numerically add these two numbers together.")
x == 2
y =  3
z = x + y
print(z)
```

I have to fix all the errors in this code but every time I run it I get an error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-f7baa07e8761> in <module>
      3 
      4 the_class = input()
----> 5 if the_class == UST220:
      6       print("Correct, this is", the_class)
      7 else:
NameError: name 'UST120' is not defined
```

I have to fix all the errors in this code, but I cannot figure out what NameError is supposed to mean

Comment: You have to keep `UST120` in quotes(string)!

Comment: The point of the exercise is that you are supposed to understand for yourself what is wrong with the code, for example by reviewing your lecture notes, or the textbook, or by putting the things you don't understand into a search engine. But also by *reading* what you are told: a `NameError` is of course an `Error` that has to do with a `Name`, and it tells you specifically that the problem with the name `UST120` is that it is `not defined`. So there are two possibilities: either you didn't want to use such a name, or you wanted it to actually *be the name of something*.

Answer (score 0):

NameError means that the variable name doesn't exists. In your case, UST220 which is used in the if condition has not been defined before. Possibly you have to put it inside quotes, if it is a string

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```py
if the_class == UST220:
```

is causing the error since UST220 is being treated as a variable which has not been instantiated. Since you're taking string input, do this instead.

```py
if the_class == 'UST220':
```